# How to access neighboring files from a setup.py when using "python -m build"?

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

Consider a Python project that uses setuptools for packaging and for some reason it needs a `setup.py` that contains certain dynamic logic at package build time. This `setup.py` needs to read a neighboring file during packaging, say, some `meta_data.json`. The data contained in this file is then supposed to be used to populate certain package properties dynamically.

A minimal `setup.py` that demonstrates such a use case would be (with a [PEP 517](https://peps.python.org/pep-0517/) conforming `[build-system]` section in `pyproject.toml` to specify setuptools as the `build-backend`):

```py
from pathlib import Path
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

# Load some external data from a neighboring file. For instance:
meta_data = (Path(__file__).parent / "meta_data.json").read_text()

# Imagine certain processing of the meta data here...

setup(
    name="mypackage",
    version="0.0.1",
    packages=find_packages(),
    # Imagine using that meta data somewhere here to populate certain package
    # properties dynamically...
)
```

Such a `setup.py` works fine when building a wheel via the old-school `python setup.py bdist_wheel`. However, invoking `setup.py` directly is [deprecated](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2021/10/setup-py-deprecated.html), and should be replaced by `python -m build`. Trying to build the package with that commands fails however with:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/build-via-sdist-fu7k7qd8/mypackage-0.0.1/meta_data.json'
```

Apparently `python -m build` doesn't run the `setup.py` in-place, and instead invokes it from a temporary location. This temporary location misses the neighboring `meta_data.json`, because the build system wasn't aware that it is needed for building.

How can I tell the build system that `meta_data.json` is needed at build time so that it becomes available during the execution of `setup.py`?

---

I guess one possibility would be to declare the `meta_data.json` as [package data](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html#package-data). However that feels wrong, because it is actually not needed to be packaged up into the wheel itself, because the data is only needed *during* building the wheel, but not during installing the wheel or at runtime like regular package data. In a sense I'm looking for something like "build time package data".